# how to make a list with all possible combinations?

Tags: python, list, numbers

I want to make a list which contains all possible 4-digit combinations of digits 1-6

e.g.`>>>list=(1111,1112,1113,.......,6666)`

how am I going to do it? I run out of ideas

Comment: Please show what you have tried. What have you thought about doing or tried? Have you also thought about the fact that you're literally just generating a list of all numbers from `1111` to `6666`? You can achieve this with a simple loop and removing certain ones (anything containing 7-9). That isn't a _great_ solution but it's something to get started with.

Comment: Check out [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

Comment: @martineau The answers in that duplicate question don't answer this one, as far as I've seen. `itertools.combinations` (or `combinations_with_replacement`, or `powerset`) won't do it, you really need `product`, as in M. Matt's answer here.

Comment: Sounds like you want [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of the 4 digits. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) for `itertools.permutations`,

Answer (score 0):

```
result = []
for i in range(1, 7):
   for j in range(1, 7):
       for k in range(1, 7): 
           for z in range (1, 7):
               result.append(1000 * i + 100 * j + 10 * k + z)
```

Comment: You had a few syntax problems, and in Python it has to be `range(1, 7)` to include 6.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.product(range(1, 7), repeat=4):
    print(i)
```

Keep in mind that `i` is a Tuple

Answer (score -2):

Make a list with all possible 1 digit numbers.

l1 = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']

for each string in the above list, concatenate all possible digits, i.e.

l2 = []

`for l in l1:
    for i in range(6): 
        l2.append(l + str(i+1))`

repeat this two more times

l3 = []

`for l in l2: 
    for i in range(6): 
        l3.append(l + str(i+1))`

l4 = []

`for l in l3: 
    for i in range(6): 
        l4.append(l + str(i+1))`